# Where can we find the science part of Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: discussion

A lot of questions are still focused on the technology part of Artificial Intelligence. However, a lot of those questions might fit better on stats.SE, or Data Science.SE. So what is left for this site?

The answer is that there is *more* than enough left for this site, we just have to explore it. In the past week, over 40 papers tagged Artificial Intelligence have been posted on [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/list/cs.AI/recent). I am sure there are a lot of papers there where we can ask good questions about, that are not on topic on stats.SE or Data.SE. So explore arXiv and ask good questions!

Comment: How many of these 40 papers match the scope of [cs.SE]? (My guess: most of those that don't fit [stats.SE], [datascience.SE] or [SO].)

Comment: @Raphael Some of them do. You are more familiar with the Computer Science site than I am, so you probably know what kind of AI questions are asked there.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have little expertise in AI of any flavor. You can probably make more sense of [our list](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence). We don't get too many AI questions, but I think most material that would be published in CS or mathematical journals would be ontopic. Plus, my opinion on what constitutes CS is not necessarily that of a majority; many papers published in CS journals are not CS in my eyes, e.g. such that (only) present or use pieces of software.