# Can we ask code explanation related to artificial intelligence

Tags: discussion

I am trying to learn about deep reinforcement learning and using OpenAI's gym but I have doubts in how its python code works. Can I ask about explanation regarding whats happening in the gym programming code implementation here or else I have to ask in data analysis.SE?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, **no.** This has been decided that it is off-topic here. See [this meta post](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/a-friendly-reminder-that-this-site-comes-from-the-science-category).